# does the stimulsoftreports.net support style tags

Tags: report

I have a letter edited in ckeditor in ASP.NET which include style tags to get the sign of the writer of the letter. I passed it to a textbox and now I want to report this letter in stimulsoftreport.net but when I do this the sign is not displayed in the report and only the text is displayed.
how can I report this letter completely?
what can I do to stimulsoft to support the style tags.
I tried the  **allow html tags** and **allow image behind** property but it did not solve the problem.
anyone have another idea?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is a limited support of the html tags.

You could read about it in the **3.6 HTML Tags** section of the [Stimulsoft Reports Universal User Manual](http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation).

You should put StiImage component on the page.